# how to split the string in a file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to capture all paths in a text file by splitting the string into an array and the word with "/java" to get the paths.

Here is my code:

```
logfile = "/home/weblogic/javaapp.txt"
log = Facter::Util::FileRead.read(logfile)
log.each_line do |line|
unless log.nil?
log.each_line do |line|
   val = line.split(/  /)
    java_path = val.grep(%r!/java!)
    java_count += 1
Facter.add("java_known_weblogic_version#{java_count}") do
 setcode do
   java_path
end
end
```

Here is my text file:

```
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java
```

The facts are returning like this:

```
java_known_weblogic_version1    ["/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java\n"]
java_known_weblogic_version10   []
java_known_weblogic_version11   []
java_known_weblogic_version12   []
java_known_weblogic_version13   ["/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java\n"]
java_known_weblogic_version14   []
java_known_weblogic_version15   []
```

How do I eliminate the `[]`  and return only the path like "/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java"?

Comment: A couple things: Learn how to format your question correctly. Stack Overflow provides [very usable help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for this, so go through it and become familiar with the techniques. Also, you don't need to beg for help; Stack Overflow is a site of volunteers who are here to try to help so that's the expectation.

Comment: Your sample code isn't valid. Please fix it. We shouldn't have to make your code syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#grep` returns an array. You might want to [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-join) it into string:

```
java_path = val.grep(%r!/java!).join(',')
```

To get rid of `\n` on ends of strings:

```
java_path = val.grep(%r!/java!).map(&:chomp).join
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is that val is returned as an array that is split based on the character that you define (/ / in your case). If you want to check on the value at each position in the array, then your best bet would be to call .each on each element within the array and then manipulate the elements that match.

```
val = line.split(/  /)
val.each do |element|
    java_path = element.match(%r!/java!)
    java_count += 1
    Facter.add("java_known_weblogic_version#{java_count}") do
        setcode do
            java_path
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: hi, when i try your code. I ma having this error undefined method `grep' for "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/bin/java":String