# How to split the strings to line by line

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a text file  which contains

```
1.6.0_43/opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java
1.6.0_43/opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/jre/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
```

I am trying to read each line by line and get the result by line by line Here is my ruby code:

```
logfile = "/home/weblogic/javacheck.txt"
java_count = 0
log = Facter::Util::FileRead.read(logfile)
unless log.nil?
    log.each_line do |line|
    if line.include?('/java')
     java_count += 1
   val = "#{line}"
```

But the output is:

```
"1.6.0_43/opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java\n1.6.0_43/opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/jre/bin/java\n1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java\n1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java\n1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java\n1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre/bin/java\n1.7.0_65/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java\n
```

How can I convert this string into line by line?

Comment: what output? your code seems to be incomplete

Comment: This is a Ruby 101 question. Have you read through a Ruby tutorial or book, or looked at the [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html) or [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html) documentation?

Comment: Hi the output i need to get is

Comment: 1.6.0_43/opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java
1.6.0_43/opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/jre/bin/java
1.5.0/opt/itm/v6.2.2/JRE/lx8266/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
1.7.0_72/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java

Comment: How is this question different from "[how to split the string in a file in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130883/how-to-split-the-string-in-a-file-in-ruby?rq=1)"? It looks like you're asking the same question repeatedly, without any progress.

Comment: The output is a string with line breaks encoded in it: `\n`. You could convert that to an array of lines: `log_array = log.split("\n")`. Then you could use `log_array.each do |line|` to iterate over the lines. Note that if you have `\n\n` in your logfile you will end up with blank elements in your array, so you may want to filter those out first if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

logfile = "/home/weblogic/javacheck.txt"
java_count = 0
log = File.open(logfile,"r")
unless log.nil?
    log.each_line do |line|
       if line.include?('/java')
          puts "#{line}"
          java_count += 1
       end
    end
end

puts "#{java_count}"
```